# Even after enabling credit card information, Google Places API Quota is not increased

Tags: google-places-api

Even after enabling credit card information, Google Places API Quota is not increased. I am getting an error status of "over_query_limit". Can someone please help me fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud platform has a Billing support channel. This service is free of charge and you can file a support case related to issues with Billing accounts using the following web form:

https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Feel free to reach out to Google support agents to solve your issue.